# How do I see who Retweeted my tweets?

Tags: twitter, retweet

Twitter now has an 'activity' tab where the 'retweets' tab used to be. How can I find out which of my tweets have been retweeted, and by whom?

Answer (score 5):

### 2016/05/29 UPDATE

Whilst there used to be a specific page dedicated to this "Retweeted of Mine" - this no longer exists.

The [twitter help](https://support.twitter.com/articles/77606) specifies:

#### Your Tweets that others have retweeted:

Go to [Notifications](https://twitter.com/i/notifications) in the top navigation bar. In the Notifications section you will see all activity concerning your Tweets — including which have recently been retweeted and by whom.

---

<strike>The [Rewteeted of Mine](https://twitter.com/retweeted_of_mine) page still exists for the moment but I believe the target you are looking for in the current interface is [Twitter > Connect > Interactions](https://twitter.com/i/connect) as listed in the [help center](https://support.twitter.com/articles/77606-faqs-about-retweets-rt):</strike>

> Go to Connect in the top navigation bar. In the Interactions section
>   you will see all activity concerning your Tweets — including which
>   have recently been retweeted and by whom.

Comment: https://twitter.com/retweeted_of_mine no longer exists and https://twitter.com/i/connect just shows https://twitter.com/i/notifications

Comment: Updated to reflect current status